# AML model api (ACI) via excel

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Is there an excel addin available right now to connect to AML model API(ACI)? I could see below solution for classic studio but not for AML.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/excel-add-in-for-web-services#steps-to-add-a-new-web-service

Answer (score 0):

Currently this feature is not available i.e.,an excel addin not available right now, however you can easily connect via a VB macro. You can open a feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/257792-machine-learning).

Please follow the below example.

https://github.com/retkowsky/AzureML_Excel

[image]